# `overflow-y: hidden` causing horizontal scrollability?

Tags: html, css

What are the circumstances under which setting overflow-y: hidden on an element can cause a horizontal scrollbar to appear that otherwise would not be there? It happened in some proprietary code I'm working on, which I cannot share here. I'd share a working code sample, but I can't trivially produce one. In general:

HTML:

```html
    <some-element></some-element>
```

This is not horizontally scrollable until adding CSS such as:

```css
    .some-element {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
```

The element suddenly becomes horizontally scrollable. I've used CSS for a very long time and never seen this one.

Comment: please create a reproduced example for better understanding so that it is clear what you mean. Look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).